# Smooth random change image .mousemove?

Tags: smoothing, mousemove

Can I make random change of imgs on .mousemove smooth with fade-in or delay or something? So idea is when imgs changes it must look smoother.
Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var images = [
        "images/banner_imgs/banner_img_1.svg",
        "images/banner_imgs/banner_img_2.svg",
        "images/banner_imgs/banner_img_3.svg",
        "images/banner_imgs/banner_img_4.svg",
        "images/banner_imgs/banner_img_5.svg"
    ];
    var currentX = 0, currentY = 0;
    $('.box').mousemove(function(e){
        if(Math.abs(currentX-e.pageX) > 30 || Math.abs(currentY-e.pageY) > 30){
            currentX = e.pageX;
            currentY = e.pageY;
            $o('.box img').attr('src',images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)]);
        }
    })
    
})
```

Comment: Overlay two `<img/>` elements and update the top layer's `opacity`.

Comment: I am sorry - do u mean in css?